# Are monkeys a subset of apes?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I wonder if "ape" is the generic, more general term than "monkey". Can one say that all primates (including monkeys) except lemurs, humans and some other few species are apes?

Comment: This one really is general reference.  I suggest you check out the Wikipedia page on primates.

Comment: [Primates (the clickable text)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primates)

Comment: OP uses the term *primate* in the question, and is clearly looking for a different term.

Comment: FYI, http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's technical usage and there's common usage.

The technical usage is determined by the biological community and there the usage states that chimps, gorillas, humans, and gibbons are apes, and that there is a distinct category of monkeys that split into New World (spider monkeys, etc) with tails) and Old world monkeys (e.g. macaques and baboons). That is, monkeys and apes are separate groups, a monkey is not an ape and an ape is not a monkey.

As to common (informal, non-technical usage), monkey includes most primates: chimps and baboons and the canonical tree swinging monkey, possibly gorillas but not humans at all. At the zoo, in the great ape house, most people will point at the animals and say 'look at the big monkey' and some kid will say 'that's not a monkey, it's an ape'.

So if anything, **informally**, it's the other way around, **'ape' is used as a kind of monkey**. But don't use that around anybody who actually knows anything.

**But technically apes and monkeys do not overlap** (though obviously related as primates).

Comment: Call a gorilla (or any other ape) a "monkey" in front of more than 2 people, and I can pretty much guarantee one of them will correct you.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yes, exactly my point with 'possibly gorillas' and 'in the great ape house'. Now that I think of it, I'd expect the same thing for a chimp, but I expect it'd be more likely for someone to start that exchange than for a gorilla.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really an "English" question but more a "taxonomy" question. But in the current taxonomy, monkeys are not a subset of apes. Rather, monkeys and apes are two distinct subsets of primates.

Comment: I do not know about taxonomy, but in Russian there is only one word for the both. That's why I asked. It is also possible that English colloquial usage differs. So you say "apes" cannot be used as a general term?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. The superset is "Primate" and "monkey", "ape", and "lemur" (and possibly others) are each subsets.

Comment: @TecBrat There is at least one other obscure and often forgotten group within primates: humans.

Comment: @Jay: No, humans are part of the subset "apes".

Comment: @TecBrat Well, apes and humans are typically grouped together as "hominoidea", but that doesn't make humans a subset of apes, any more than the fact that both apes and monkeys are called primates makes apes a subset of monkeys. See, e.g. http://www.emory.edu/LIVING_LINKS/pdf_attachments/PRIMATE%20TAXONOMY.pdf, which divides hominoidea into 3 families: gibbons, apes, and humans. Of course classification systems are human inventions. It is not a scientific fact that hominoidea are divided into 3 families and not 2 or 4, in the sense that I could perform some experiment ...

Comment: ... to prove that these similar species should be divided up this way rather than that way. What criteria are used to group similar species together are arbitrary choices. And there are competing taxonomic systems out there: it's not like all biologists agree on the best taxonomy and it is now fixed for ever. So if it amuses you to group yourself under apes, go ahead, I'm sure you can find some school of biologists who agree with you. But traditionally, "primates" have been divided into humans, apes, old world monkeys, new world monkeys, and pro-simians.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4332/discussion-between-tecbrat-and-jay)

Answer (score 6):

***[Ape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominoidea)*** refers to the clade of animals belonging to the superfamily *Hominoidea*, which is the same superfamily that contains *Homo sapiens*. Humans, in other words, are biologically apes.

***Monkey***, on the other hand, is **not** a clade, since there are two different groups, the [Catarrhine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catarrhini) or "Old World" monkeys (superfamily *Cercopithecoidea*, found in Africa and Eurasia only) and the [Platyrrhine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_World_monkey) or "New World" monkeys (found in the Americas only -- these are the ones with prehensile tails). The apes are related more closely to the Old World monkeys.

Consequently, if anything, *ape* is a subset of *monkey*, rather than the other way around. Though that's not strictly true, either. Check the [tree diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate#Historical_and_modern_terminology) on the "Primates" Wikipedia page that tchrist mentioned to see the details.

Answer (score 2):

**Simians** is the term I would use for the "higher" primates. *Simian* means monkey-like, and the term does correspond to a scientific classification, *Simiiformes*. **Primates** is arguable more common, but if we are to be as scientific as the previous answers demand, we must note that primates include lemurs, tarsiers, and other animals which many people would not understand to be closely related to monkeys and apes, as wellas humans.

In everyday speaking, most people will use *apes* and *monkeys* interchangeably as the umbrella term, either out of ignorance of the scientific distinction or for the sake of simplicity. This is loosely comparable to calling all dogs *hounds* or referring to horses as *ponies*— it may be incorrect, but in non-academic arenas, it gets the sense across.

Comment: So what term is more common in colloquial - apes or monkeys?

Comment: @Anixx It is impossible to say for certain, as both are common as well as mixed into many other terms and expressions— *ape house*, *monkey wrench*, *going ape*, *monkey business*, *apeshit*, *monkey model*, *apeman*, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a taxonomy question, but since there is no Taxonomy.SE...

Both belong to an order commonly called [Primates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate). While this isn't technically correct, you can consider primates as being split into "simians" and "prosimians" (these words aren't used a lot, but sometimes you will hear them in conversational English). Mostly "prosimians" are lemurs.

"Simians" are generally split up into monkeys and apes. They are **separate** things. This is important because if you call an animal that is considered an ape a "monkey" (or visa versa), some brainiac is bound to correct you. That's annoying enough IMHO to learn the difference. :-)

Monkeys are a rather diverse grouping. Mostly they are smallish tree-dwelling primates (who are not lemurs), although Baboons are monkeys, are rather large, and live on the African savannah.

**So generally what you do is learn what Apes are, and you are fairly safe in calling all other primates (not found on Madagascar) "monkeys".**

So what are Apes? They are Gibbons, Siamangs (collectively known as lesser apes), and Orangutans, Gorillas, Chimpanzees, Bonobos, and Man (collectively known as greater apes).

Humans of course are a special case. There are those who (generally in my experience for religous reasons) insist Humans are not animals, and thus certianly aren't apes. They tend to feel very strongly about this, so I would advise against referring to humans as "apes" either, unless you know for a fact your audience doesn't include any such people.

Comment: Alas poor Loris!  I knew him, Horatio.  You also neglect the bushbabies.

Comment: BZZT: Orangutangs are great apes, not lesser ones. And how can you tell whether you have any apes in the audience?

Comment: @tchrist - Fixing the Orang bit (along with the spelling. Needed to check both, but RL intruded). As for other technicalities, I **stated up front** (see paragraph 2, and all the uses of words like "generally") I'm avoiding those. They don't come up in conversation hardly ever, and don't affect what I'm trying to say here.